# Change ExpansionPanel arrow color on expanded parent ExpansionPanel in material-ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to figure out how to get material-ui themes to work how I want it to, and having some trouble.

what I want is for my expansion panels to have a different arrow color when expanded to make them more visible. The catch is that I need this behavior *only on parent expansion panels, and not expansion panels within expansion panels.*

Currently I have written my material-ui theme so that only parent expansion panels have their color change when expanded, like so:
[image]

My issue is that the black arrow is hard to see against the dark-blue panel summary. I would like to be able to change that color to white, but *only when in a parent panel*. So basically, whenever an ExpansionPanelSummary is blue, the arrow should be white.

I can't seem to find a CSS control to do what I want. Here is my theme for ExpansionPanelSummary that controls the color (I think my CSS for the arrow should be in here somewhere but I'm not sure):

```js
      MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
        root: {
          minHeight: "0px",
          minWidth: "0px",
          "&$expanded": {
            //Elevation 1
            boxShadow:
              "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
            minHeight: "0px",
            backgroundColor: "#3f51b5",
            color: "white"
          },
          ".MuiExpansionPanelDetails-root &$expanded": {
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            color: "black"
          }
        },
        content: {
          minWidth: "0px",
          margin: "8px 0px",
          "&$expanded": {
            margin: "8px 0px"
          }
        }
      },
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is one way of achieving this which uses the `MuiExpansionPanelSummary-expandIcon` class to target the icon and overrides this back to the [default](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.1/packages/material-ui/src/IconButton/IconButton.js#L19) for the nested expansion panel.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();

const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
      root: {
        minHeight: "0px",
        minWidth: "0px",
        "&$expanded": {
          //Elevation 1
          boxShadow:
            "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
          minHeight: "0px",
          backgroundColor: "#3f51b5",
          color: "white",
          "& .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-expandIcon": {
            color: "white"
          }
        },
        ".MuiExpansionPanelDetails-root &$expanded": {
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          color: "black",
          "& .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-expandIcon": {
            color: defaultTheme.palette.action.active
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default myTheme;
```

[image: Edit custom ExpansionPanelSummary theme]

Answer (score 2):

```
import { React, Component } from 'react'; 
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
    const styles = {
        expand_icon : {
            color: "white"
        }
    }
    
    class ListComponent extends Component {
    
        render() {
            const { classes } = this.props;
            return (
    
                <div>
                    <Accordion className={classes.accordion}>
                        <AccordionSummary
                            className={classes.accordion_summary}
                            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.expand_icon} />}
                            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                            id="panel1a-header"
                        >
                            <Typography></Typography>
                        </AccordionSummary>
                    </Accordion>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ListComponent);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes